# A particular class which satisfies all ZF axioms except for the axiom of infinity

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

Suppose we have a non-empty transitive class $\mathcal{C}$, meaning that if $x$ is in the class, then all its elements are also in the class. Suppose also that $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies the axiom schema of specification and the following property: If a set $x$ is such that all its elements are elements of $\mathcal{C}$, then there exists an element $y$ in the class $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x\subseteq y$.

I have to show that $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies all ZF axioms except for the axiom of infinity. Also, I have to find an example of such a class $\mathcal{C}$ such that the axiom of infinity is not satisfied.

I could prove that such a class $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies all ZF axioms except for the axiom of infinity. It is not very hard. For example, for the axiom of union, I just take the usual union and show that it is contained in $\mathcal{C}$, so I should have that this union is contained in some element of $\mathcal{C}$, and then by specification the union is an element of $\mathcal{C}$. The other axioms are similar to prove.

So, it only remains to find a class $\mathcal{C}$ which does not satisfy the axiom of infinity. We have the functional relation $V$ inductively defined as $V_{\alpha}=\bigcup_{\beta \in \alpha}\mathcal{P}\left (V_{\beta}\right )$ for every ordinal $\alpha$, where $V_{\emptyset}=\emptyset$. It is known that if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $V_{\alpha}$ satisfies all ZFC axioms except (perhaps) for the axiom of infinity, which is satisfied if and only if $\omega \in \alpha$. Therefore, I have the candidate $V_{\omega}$, which satisfies all ZF axioms except for the axiom of infinity, which is not satisfied because $\omega \not\in \omega$. Of course, $V_{\omega}$ is transitive, but I could not prove that it satisfies that if a set $x$ is such that all its elements are elements of $V_{\omega}$, then there exists an element $y\in V_{\omega}$ such that $x\subseteq y$ (indeed, I think that assertion is false).

Which $\mathcal{C}$ would you take?

EDIT: Some of you were asking where this question came from. I took it from "Teoría axiomática de conjuntos: Una introducción" by Roberto Cignoli. It is written in spanish. This is a screenshot of the exercise:

[image: Specific exercise]

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with the problem since, as stated, it is false. On the basis of the other axioms, one easily check that $V_\omega\subseteq\mathcal C$, and therefore the requirement that infinity fails is incompatible with the requirement that subsets of $\mathcal C$ are subsets of members of $\mathcal C$.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, not only $\cal C$ satisfy ZF(including infinity), even if you change "$\cal C$ satisfies the axiom schema of specification" into "$\cal C$ satisfies the axiom schema of specification to $Δ_0$ formulas" it still satisfy all of ZF

Comment: It seems to me like someone wanted you to find a transitive model of ZF-Infinity, but instead made a mistake. Where did you find this question?

Comment: Note that if $\cal C$ is such a class, then it must contain *all* the ordinals (let $\alpha$ be an ordinal such that $\alpha\subseteq\cal C$, then $\alpha\subseteq x$ for some $x\in\cal C$, use specification [with a $\Delta_0$-formula] to get $x\cap\rm Ord\in\cal C$, now either this equals $\alpha$, or there is some $\beta>\alpha$ for which $\beta\in x\cap\rm Ord$, then $\alpha\in\beta\in x\in\cal C$ and by transitivity $\alpha\in\cal C$.)

Comment: $V_{\omega}$ is transitive and satisfies ZFC - Infty +($\neg$ Infty) but does not satisfy the last sentence of your 1st paragraph. No transitive model of ZF -Infty + ($\neg$ Infty) can satisfy that sentence.

Comment: Why doesn't $y=x \cup \{ x \}$ satisfy the last sentence of his first paragraph?

Comment: I have just added a screenshot. Maybe I did not understand correctly the question...

Comment: @RobertShore Since, for example, $\omega \subseteq V_\omega$ but $\omega+1\notin V_\omega$

Comment: @solomeo I think you read it right and the question is just wrong. It is actually a common exercise to show that a transitive class is a model of all of ZF if and only if those two conditions hold.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So when we're talking about a set $x$, we're not restricted to objects that are sets within the model?  Because $\omega \notin V_\omega$.

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, any subset of the model, not necessarily an element of the model. (My spanish isn’t great but this seems evident from the screenshot OP provided.)

Comment: Then I don't understand how $\mathcal C(y)$ is being used within the quantifier.  I suspect that something is missing there.  As written, it seems syntactically incorrect to me.

Comment: The only way I can make sense of this, is if the meta-theory itself is ZF-Infinity.

Comment: @RobertShore I think $\mathcal C(y)$ just means the same thing as $y\in \mathcal C.$ In other words $\mathcal C$ is being treated as the formula defining the class. So for instance $x\subset \mathcal C$ is actually an abbreviation for $(\forall y\in x) \mathcal C(y).$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. By $\mathcal{C}\left (y\right )$ the author means that $y$ is an element of the class $\mathcal{C}$. Sorry if it was not clear enough.

Comment: In that case I agree with all the other comments that the statement is just wrong.

Comment: @solomeo Sorry, the “only if” in my previous comment to you was wrong, unless we require the class to be proper.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is true.  Every element of $V_\omega$ is a member of $V_n$ for some $n \in \omega$ so every element of $V_\omega$ is finite.  That means that if $x \in V_\omega,~ \exists N \in \omega \text{ with } z \in V_N ~\forall z \in x$.  But then $x \subset y= x \cup \{x\} \in V_{N+1} \subset V_\omega$.

Comment: This does not address the question.

Comment: Wasn't he asking for a proof that if all elements of $x$ are in $V_\omega$, then $\exists~y \in V_\omega$ with $x \subseteq y$?

Comment: Robert, all elements of $V_\omega$ are in $V_\omega$.

Comment: All elements of $\omega$ are in $V_\omega$, but that doesn't mean a set containing all of those elements is in $V_\omega$.

Comment: There you go, so what you need to prove is false for $x=V_\omega$.

Comment: But $V_\omega$ isn't a set *within the model* $V_\omega$.  My construction, in contrast, shows that if you have a set that's *already within* $V_\omega$, you can construct a strictly larger set that's also within $V_\omega$, which is where I think the OP was stuck.

Comment: No Robert, that's not it.